# Как подключить Encore для проекта Symfony в Docker-Compose?

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, symfony, yarn

Перекидываю Symfony-проект под docker-compose. Встала проблема переноса Encore'a.

Моя попытка следующая:

В docker-compose.yml :

```
compose:
    image: composer:1.9
    container_name: compose
    volumes:
        - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    command: composer install
    command: composer yarn install
    command: composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle


  encore:
    container_name: encore
    image: node:alpine
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    command: [ "yarn", "dev-server", "--host=0.0.0.0" ]
    command: yarn install
    command: yarn add @symfony/webpack-encore --dev
    command: encore yarn build
    command: encore dev --watch
```

На выходе при запуске docker-compose up указывает, что symfony/webpack-encore-bundle композер установил, но выдает ошибку:

```
encore        | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895
encore        |   throw err;
encore        |   ^
encore        | 
encore        | Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/html/encore'
encore        |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)
encore        |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:27)
encore        |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
encore        |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
encore        |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
encore        |   requireStack: []
encore        | }
encore exited with code 1
```

Я понимаю, что здесь мне логически неоткуда брать модуль Encore, но иных вариантов я не нашёл в интернете.
Я не понимаю как и из какого образа мне "вытащить" применение команды Encore в docker-compose  через command.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём моя ошибка и как её разрешить.

Comment: действительно впервые вижу, чтобы сборщика пытались установить как отдельный контейнер. странное решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.

Воспользовался методичкой отсюда:
https://github.com/thecodingmachine/symfony-vuejs

Чтобы внедрить в свой проект, я в свой docker-composer.yml добавил один сервис, подправив версию на поновее. Encore работает.

```
  app:
    image: thecodingmachine/php:7.4-v3-apache-node12
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.backend=app
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:app.localhost
    environment:
      APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: "public/"
      PHP_EXTENSION_XDEBUG: "1"
      PHP_INI_MEMORY_LIMIT: "1G"
      # Symfony
      APP_ENV: "dev"
      APP_SECRET: "8d2a5c935d8ef1c0e2b751147382bc75"
      DATABASE_URL: "mysql://root:root@db/mydatabase"
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}:rw
    command: bash -c "yarn install && yarn dev --watch"
```

upd: исправил command и убрал лишний сервис

Comment: `yarn install` и `yarn upgrade` не запустятся

Comment: Да? А в каком сервисе их можно устанавливать? yarn install писал вручную

Comment: Я symfony не использую; В docker-compose.yml игнорируются все command кроме последней; поэтому, если хотите, чтоб запустилось, пишите в одной: yarn install && yarn upgrade && ...

Comment: Да, спасибо за подсказку. Написал `command: bash -c "yarn install && yarn dev --watch"` и обе команды отобразились в консоли. Теперь понятно почему другие команды не работали.

Answer (score 0):

Многошаговый `command` не пройдет.

Либо пишите скрипт-обертку с шагами и вызывайте в `command`,
либо делайте `Dockerfile` с `RUN` шагами.